# SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier '{'. import call expects exactly one argument. JavaScript HTML

Tags: javascript, html, firebase

I have following lines at the bottom of my `<body>`:

```
<script type="module" src="../js/firebase.js"></script>
<script src="../js/common.js"></script>
```

Here is `firebase.js`:

```
import { initializeApp } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.10.0/firebase-app.js";
import { getAuth, createUserWithEmailAndPassword } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.10.0/firebase-auth.js";
import { getDatabase } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.10.0/firebase-database.js";

const firebaseConfig = {
    ...
};

export const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
```

And here is an import inside `common.js`:

```
import {app} from './firebase.js';
...
```

This import raises `SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier '{'. import call expects exactly one argument`

Answer (score 1):

Only `module`s can use `import`.

So change

```
<script src="../js/common.js"></script>
```

to

```
<script src="../js/common.js" type="module"></script>
```

If that doesn't fix your problem, then the import you show is not the problematic import.

Make sure you don't try to import a `default` export as a named `export`, or vice versa.